# Not able to get web.py sessions to work using python 2.6 on OS X

Tags: python, web.py

I can not seem to get this script to work:

```
import web
web.config.debug=False

urls = (
  '/', 'hello',
  '/bye/', 'bye')


app = web.application(urls, globals())
session = web.session.Session(app, web.session.DiskStore('sessions'),
                              initializer={'count': 0})

class hello:
    def GET(self):
        session.count += 1
        return "You visited " + str(session.count) + " pages."

class bye:
    def GET(self):
        session.kill()
        return ("Bye, web!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This is code available from the web.py documentation page: http://webpy.org/cookbook/sessions

When I try to access the 'hello' page by going to `http://localhost:1234/`, the application returns an internal server error.

Here is the output from the terminal upon accessing this resource:

```
http://0.0.0.0:1234/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/web/application.py", line 237, in process
    return self.handle()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/web/application.py", line 228, in handle
    return self._delegate(fn, self.fvars, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/web/application.py", line 409, in _delegate
    return handle_class(cls)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/web/application.py", line 385, in handle_class
    return tocall(*args)
  File "testing.py", line 15, in GET
    session.count += 1
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/web/session.py", line 69, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._data, name)
AttributeError: 'ThreadedDict' object has no attribute 'count'

127.0.0.1:49207 - - [20/Mar/2012 20:34:01] "HTTP/1.1 GET /" - 500 Internal Server Error
```

Can any web.py expert out there tell me what is going on?

Comment: Your code works as is with Python 2.7.2 and web.py 0.36.

Comment: I have the same problem, anyone could help?

Comment: I don't know if this might be the case but if you're using diskstore there should be a sessions folder in the same folder where your web.py code is. It should be writable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed and configured Macports version of Python 2.7.2 and still I get similar results.

It just occurred to me that this may be a permissions issues, because of where the sessions are stored. I tried running with 'sudo' using both Python 2.7 and Python 2.6 that came natively from Apple, and running

```
sudo python myfile.py 1234
```

Web.py sessions is now working. @Eduardo Ivanec: I will attempt to set up my Python development environment using your instructions. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Change
    app = web.application(urls, globals())

to 
    app = web.application(urls, locals())

Comment: I tried this, and same result. I think there is something up with my python installation/configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as is with Python 2.7.2 and web.py 0.36. If you're running anything older I'd upgrade, as the example is valid.

Your initializer doesn't seem to be working correctly. You can try using this snippet instead to initialize the count attribute on its first use:

```
class hello:
    def GET(self):
        try:
            session.count += 1
        except AttributeError:
            session.count = 1
        return "You visited " + str(session.count) + " pages."
```

Edit: since you're using OS X, [this link](http://docwhat.org/2011/06/virtualenv-on-os-x/) may be of help. It describes how to set up a brand new Python environment using standard OS X tools and virtualenv. I use GNU/Linux, but it looks nice. Also, you can download a ready to go version in the [official download page](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.2/).

Comment: I tried this, and still no dice. I think there is something the matter with my python installation/configuration.

Comment: @topmulch: see my edit about setting up a new Python environment in OS X.

Comment: nice documentation. I never set up virtualenv, and I should. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this problem before. 
For 500 internal error, please use chmod -R 755 your_foler/sessions
to change your folder's permission.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the python version. I had the same problem and I solved it when I executed  2.7 version of python.
Just doing `> python2.7 code.py` and the sessions works perfectly.